# How to manually trigger a CSImportExtension call in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, corespotlight

I created an ImportExtension using the template in Xcode, and implemented the `-[ImportExtension updateAttributes:forFileAtURL:error:]` method. I have tried searching for the corresponding file in Spotlight and the method is not called. How can I make this method be called?

Xcode Version: 13.2.1

iOS Version: iOS 15.2